# Simple condition for asymptotic normality of MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, inference

Are these conditions sufficient for asymptotic normality of MLE? If it is, pls. let me know the references.

1-First and second derivatives of $\ell(\theta,\eta)$ are defined. 
2- The Fisher information matrix be non-singular and continuous with respect to the parameters $\theta$ and $\eta$.

Comment: Why don't you try proving the asymptotic normality of the MLE using this set of assumptions and see if you need any more?

Comment: Another condidion is that your parameter cannot be on the boundary of its domain, so you might want to revise to have the first and second derivatives of $\ell(\theta,\eta)|_{\theta^*,\eta^*}$ be the goal. Also, a simple test is to see if the log-likelihood function approaches a quadratic as n $\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Dear fg nu ... which set of assumption?

Comment: Dear Eupraxis 1981 ... I just want know if these 2 conditions are sufficient for asymp. Normality or not

Answer (score 3):

Asymptotic normality is usually proven for a local maximum of the likelihood function. I paste below the conditions as stated in **T. Amemiya (1985) Advanced Econometrics, ch. 4**, for *extremum* or $M$-estimators in general. $T$ is sample size, $\theta$ is the unknown parameter vector, and  $\theta_0$ is the true values, $\mathbf y$ is the data sample, $Q_T(\mathbf y, \theta)$ is the objective function, $\hat \theta_T$ is the ML estimator. $\Theta_T$ is the set containing the roots of the equation $\frac {\partial Q_T(\mathbf y, \theta)}{\partial \theta} =0$ corresponding to local maxima.

[image]

Variations do exist. For example, if $Q_T(\mathbf y, \theta)$ is concave over the parameter space for any $\mathbf y$, then uniform convergence (**4.1.2.-C**) can be replaced by point-wise convergence. Also, there are alternative ways to express some of the conditions. For example condition **4.1.3-B** may be replaced by its own sufficient condition, the local dominance condition : for some neighborhood of $\theta_0$, $N(\theta_0)$,
$$E\left[\text {sup}_{\theta \in N(\theta_0)}  ||\partial^2Q_T/\partial \theta\partial\theta'||\right] <\infty$$.

**ADDENDUM**
Responding to @whuber's comment (my meta-response can be found in the comments), consider an i.i.d sample $\{x_i,\, i=1,...,n\}$ from a uniform $U(0,\theta)$. Then the ML estimator for $\theta$ is

$$\hat \theta_{ML} = \max_i x_i = X_{(n)}$$

The asymptotic distribution of the maximum of an i.i.d sample is known not to be normal. This is an example that asymptotic normality requires more conditions than those stated in the question.

Comment: The question posits two conditions and asks whether they are sufficient. Thus, a logically valid answer will either (a) demonstrate they are sufficient or else (b) provide a counterexample in which the two given conditions hold but asymptotic normality does not.

Comment: @whuber Another logically valid answer is to use a reliable source that states the full set of conditions, which is what I did. Then, if these conditions are more numerous than the conditions stated in the question, it follows that the latter are not sufficient. Moreover my answer, by providing the full set of conditions, could help future users that may wonder "what are the sufficient conditions for asymptotic normality to hold", and may come to CV looking for an answer. Certainly, adding counter examples would make for a fuller and more educational answer... so I added one such example.

Comment: That this is not a logically valid approach is exemplified by the Central Limit Theorem, for which numerous non-equivalent sets of conditions are known. "More numerous" is not meaningful, either (although "logically is implied by" would be). I do not see anything in the material you quoted that claims these are necessary *and sufficient* conditions, which is what you seem to be talking about here. Moreover, your addendum is not a counterexample because its log likelihood fails to be differentiable everywhere.